# Angular keeps adding an empty option to select and unable to instantiate a selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm losing my mind trying to get this to work, I've been asked to fix some combo boxes that update a setting contained in an array in the controller, the setting in question contains a value (0 or 1) which have each been assigned to the two options in the combo. The combo box simply changes the value to either 0 or 1.

Its not my own code, I'm working with what has been given to me and so far have been unable to get it working.

When the page is first loaded, this is the empty box that is present
`<option value="? number:1 ?" selected="selected"></option>`
When either of the two options are selected, this empty option disappears and it functions normally until the page is reloaded.

I've tried using ng-selected with the settings value to no avail, I've also tried ng-init which also didn't work. I also tried setting the selected option after the page has loaded using $(document).ready and iterating through each select on the page.

I've added console.logs() to check if the value is being retrieved successfully and not null (It isn't and is the correct value of 1)

The select

```
<select ng-change="updateSelect(setting.value,setting.setting_id,setting.name,setting.category_id)" class="form-select form-control" ng-model="setting.value" id="{{setting.setting_id}}" style="margin-top: 8px" required>
                <option value="0" ng-selected="setting.value == 0">No</option>
                <option value="1" ng-selected="setting.value == 1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Manually iterating through each select

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement: 'top'
    });
    $('select').each(function () {
        var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
        var settingValue = settingsData[selectId];

        console.log("Selectbox: " + selectId);

        $(this).val(settingValue);
    });
});
```

The updateSelect function

```
$scope.updateSelect = function (value, id, name, cat) {
    var tempObj = {}
    tempObj['id'] = id;
    tempObj['value'] = value;
    tempObj['name'] = name;
    tempObj['category_id'] = cat;

    var updated = $scope.checkSettingInArray(tempObj);

    if (updated) {
        console.log("setting updated");
        console.log($scope.listOfChanges);
    }
$scope.previousValue = value;
$scope.previousID = id;
};
```

I genuinely do not understand why this isn't working, I've been going through old posts and tried various solutions from them to no avail.

Comment: please update a working example where the issue happens and update what needs to be fixed, there is angularjs and jquery code, why do you need both?

Comment: As I said, this isn't my code, this is simply what I was given. The rest of the repo is built like the code above, its not ideal but I just have to work with what I'm given.
I can't upload much more code than that without getting in trouble, the code given is what is relevant.

Comment: check if you have a variable "setting" or try at very first use `$scope.setting.value=0`